# css vertical align for <label>

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, alignment

I am trying to align my menu button vertically to the height of my container.

The container is the header of my page in which the menu button should be placed vertically centered.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"><label for="toggle">&equiv;</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background-color:#D9303D;
    height:9%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    font-size:38px;
    z-index: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: transform .6s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of height for any div is a bad practice in CSS. Try to use margin or padding instead. You can use these CSS code to design. Hope it will help you to design your page.

```
#container {
    background-color:#D9303D;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

label {
   float: right;
   margin: auto 0;
    font-size:38px;
    z-index: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: transform .6s;
}
```

there could be some gap between the header container and the browser window. to eliminate that you can add another line in css..

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick-

```
#container {display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 2px solid #000;
height:200px; 
width:100px;
```

}

Adjust the height, width , Border according to your need.